# Simple python calculator doesn't return a result

Tags: python-3.x

```
print("choose an operation")
print("enter 1 for addition")
print("enter 2 for subtraction")
print("enter 3 for multipication")
print("enter 4 for division")
a = input(print("enter a number from 1 to 4"))
b = input(print('enter the first number'))
c = input(print('enter the second number'))
d = int(b)
e = int(c)
if a == 1: (print(d+e))
elif a == 2: (print(d-e))
elif a == 3: (print(d*e))
elif a == 4: (print(d/e))
else:(print("invalid"))
```

trying to build a mini calculator
when run it asks for prompt properly but does not execute any calculations and just prints invalid

Answer (score 0):

```
print("choose an operation")
print("enter 1 for addition")
print("enter 2 for subtraction")
print("enter 3 for multipication")
print("enter 4 for division")
print("enter a number from 1 to 4")
a = input()
print('enter the first number')
b = input()
print('enter the second number')
c = input()
d = int(b)
e = int(c)
if a == "1": (print(d+e))
elif a == "2": (print(d-e))
elif a == "3": (print(d*e))
elif a == "4": (print(d/e))
else:(print("invalid"))
```

input returns a string - so your comparison to resolve the operation should look like this

Comment: Additionally wrapping your print statement inside the input doesn't make sense. print doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
print("choose an operation")
print("enter 1 for addition")
print("enter 2 for subtraction")
print("enter 3 for multipication")
print("enter 4 for division")
print("enter a number from 1 to 4")
a = input()
print('enter the first number')
b = input()
print('enter the second number')
c = input()
d = int(b)
e = int(c)
if a == "1":
     print(d+e)
elif a == "2":
     print(d-e)
elif a == "3":
     print(d*e)
elif a == "4": 
     print(d/e)
else:
     print("invalid")
```